# mysqldump resume after connection failed

Tags: mysql, linux

I started a dump of mydatabse its over 5gb and now it is giving out a error after downloading 2gb the error is mentioned below.

I am confused have not tried anything.

```
mysqldump -uroot -proot -h123.123.123.123 example >example.sql
```

```
mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server when dumping table `a_dit` at row: 444444
```

And I don't want to start all again.

It stopped at a table, is there anyway to resume from the left table or to check and resume the dumping process?

Comment: Start your `mysqldump` next time in a `screen` session so that `mysqldump` continues to run even if the connection is lost.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can

```
mysqldump -uroot -p db_name --skip-create-options table_name --where='id>666666'
```

or you can also use

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'data_path.sql' from table where id>666666
```

I  would recommend to start again and dump every table on its own.